# Blur effect disappears when testing flash app on iOS5 device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, blur

with Flash Professional CS6 I build an iOS app (AIR SDK 3.4.0.2710). This app features a MovieClip with blur effect applied with AS3 code. No problem when I run this app in the Flash simulator. But, when I test the app directly on a device (iOS5), the blur effect disappears.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY SOLVED: it seems when using **GPU** rendering mode the Blur effect (and any other flash.filters.* package effect) can't be easily rendered in iOS:

1. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/918235
2. http://forums.adobe.com/message/3934192#3934192#3934192